# Box2d :roll soft body ball

Tags: box2d, libgdx, game-physics

I made a soft body ball int box2d that looks like that:

[image]

Every point of the circle is a box2d body and every line is a distance joint.
How can i roll it? I don't want to change the world gravity and just let it roll , I want it to start spinning from the center (not every circle point independent).

I just need the geeneral idea ,not code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general idea is to apply the right force to each body. If you want rotation - these forces are normals to the vectors from the center of the ball to the center of the body.